# Helm split global section

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm `values.yaml` file like below

```
global:
  foo: bar
  foo1: bar1

random-chart:
  fooo: baar
```

My use case is to append values in both `global` and `random-chart` during run time.
After appending values, the chart looks like this.

```
global:
  foo: bar
  foo1: bar1

random-chart:
  fooo: baar

global:
  secret: password

random-chart:
  secret1: password1
```

Since there's 2 different `global` and `random-chart` keys. Will it work as intended and is it a good practice to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably won't work as intended.

The [YAML 1.2.2 spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#3211-nodes) notes (emphasis from original):

> The content of a *mapping* node is an unordered set of *key/value* node *pairs*, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique.

And in [discussing loading errors](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#33-loading-failure-points) continues:

> ... mapping keys may not be unique ....

So the YAML file you show has a mapping with two keys both named `global` and two keys both named `random-chart`, and that's not valid.  Depending on the specific YAML library that's being used, this might be interpreted as a loading error, or the library might just pick the last value of `global`.

In general, it's hard to work with YAML files using line-oriented shell tools, since there are so many syntactic variations.  A dedicated library in a higher-level language will usually work better.  For example, using the Python [PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) library:

```py
import yaml
with open('values.in.yaml', 'r') as f:
  values = yaml.safe_load(f)
values['global']['secret'] = 'password'
values['random-chart']['secret-1'] = 'password1'
with open('values.out.yaml', 'w') as f:
  yaml.dump(values. f)
```

Two other possibilities to consider: you can have multiple `helm install -f` options, so it's possible to write out a file with just the values you're adding, and those will be merged with other settings (you do not need to repeat the values from the chart's `values.yaml` file).  Depending on your environment, you also may find it easier to dynamically write out JSON files, particularly if you don't need to re-read the base chart; setups like Jenkins or Javascript applications will have built-in JSON support, and valid JSON turns out to be valid YAML.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried using PyYAML but found it removes comments which will create problems in my use case, also tried `yq` module which has a similar bug. Multiple `helm install -f` is also a breaker as I'll have to add another file. The more the files, the more burden will be on the people who support this use case after me.